# How to derive Paley-Zigmund Inequality proof

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

The Paley-Zygmund inequality is given by

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{P}( Z > \theta\operatorname{E}[Z] )
\ge (1-\theta)^2 \frac{\operatorname{E}[Z]^2}{\operatorname{E}[Z^2]}
\end{equation}

I want to prove it. I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality) Wikipedia article on the Paley-Zygmund inequality which states that I can decompose the random variable $X$ like so

\begin{equation}
E[Z] = E[Z\mathbf{1}_{\{Z\leq\theta E[Z]\}}]+E[Z\mathbf{1}_{\{Z>\theta E[Z]\}}]
\end{equation}

the article then states that
\begin{align}
E[Z\mathbf{1}_{\{Z\leq\theta E[Z]\}}] \leq & \; \theta E[Z] \;\;\; \text{and}\\
E[Z\mathbf{1}_{\{Z>\theta E[Z]\}}] \leq & \; \sqrt{E[Z^2]P(Z>\theta E[Z])}
\end{align}

Plugging this into the first equation yields

\begin{align}
E[Z] \leq & \; \theta E[Z] + \sqrt{E[Z^2]P(Z>\theta E[Z])} \\
\iff (1-\theta)^2 \frac{E[Z]^2}{E[Z^2]} \leq & \; P(Z>\theta E[Z]).
\end{align}

I have two questions: 1) The decomposition makes intuitive sense. Either way, exactly one of the conditions is true, so the equality holds. However, is there a more formal way / analytical approach to support this statement? 2) How are the upper bounds for the two expected values of the indicator variable derived? I would appreciate an answer which is kept quite simple as I am not a (pure) mathematician.

/edit: Possibly should have posted this to math.stackexchange. Maybe a mod can move the question.

Comment: Check this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501927/proof-of-paley-zygmund-inequality-lower-bound-for-upper-tail-of-square-integrab might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this question before. The answer states my procedure exactly, but without explanation on my two questions.

Comment: I hope that the following answer will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part of your question we have that: We have that $Z\geq 0$ thus the domain can be decomposed as $Z\geq 0= (Z\leq \theta \mathbb{E}[Z]) \cup (Z> \theta \mathbb{E}[Z])$

$$\mathbb{E}[Z] = \int_{Z\geq 0} z p(z)dz = \int_{Z\leq \theta \mathbb{E}[Z]} zp(z)dz + \int_{Z> \theta \mathbb{E}[Z]}zp(z) = \\
\mathbb{E}[Z\times 1_{Z\leq \theta \mathbb{E}[Z]}] + \mathbb{E}[Z\times 1_{Z>\theta \mathbb{E}[Z]}] $$

For the second part:

$$\mathbb{E}[Z\times 1_{Z\leq \theta \mathbb{E}[Z]}] =  \int_{Z\leq \theta \mathbb{E}[Z]} zp(z)dz \leq \int_{Z\leq \theta \mathbb{E}[Z]} max(z)p(z)dz \\
 = \theta \mathbb{E}[Z]\int p(z)dz = \theta \mathbb{E}[Z]$$

Also, the $Z$ has finite variance thus $\mathbb{E}[Z^{2}]<\infty,$ $Z$ is square integrable, so we can use the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality for $L^{2}$,

$$\mathbb{E}[Z\times 1_{Z>\theta \mathbb{E}[Z]}] = \int z1_{Z> \theta\mathbb{E}[Z]}p(z) \leq (\int z^{2}p(z)dz)^{1/2} (\int 1_{Z> \theta \mathbb{E}[Z]}^{2}p(z)dz)^{2}\\
=\mathbb{E}[Z^{2}]^{1/2}\mathbb{P}(Z> \theta \mathbb{E}[Z])^{1/2} $$

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear!

Comment: @MarcelB In the interval $Z\leq \theta \mathbb{E}[Z]$ the largest possible value that $Z$ can take is $\theta \mathbb{E}[Z]$.  You mean why the integral on $q(z)$ disappears?

Comment: You are quick, I wanted to find an answer myself, that's why I deleted the question. Thanks for the response! And no nevermind that, I misread!

Comment: But yeah, actually I wonder why the integral disappears. It must equal 1, which would make sense for a pdf on the full domain but I'm not operating on the full domain.. why is it 1?

Comment: Another way to view this is to consider that you take the max of $(z1_{Z\leq \theta \mathbb{E}[Z]})$ and you let the integral lie on the whole domain i.e. $Z\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to understand the argument without writing any integrals.

Why the decomposition is true? Because it is a pointwise inequality. Let $ a = \theta E[Z]$. The following holds for any random variable $Z$ and any $a \in \mathbb R$:
$$
Z = Z \cdot 1_{Z \le a} + Z \cdot 1_{\{Z > a\}}. \quad (*)
$$
To see this recall that random variables are just real-valued functions on the sample space. The inequality reads
$$
Z(\omega) = Z(\omega) \cdot 1_{\{Z(\omega) \le a\}} + Z(\omega) \cdot 1_{\{Z(\omega) > a\}}.
$$
A bit more simply, note that $1 = 1_{\{Z \le a\}} + 1_{\{Z > a\}}$ and multiply both sides by $Z$.

Next, we take the expectation of both sides of (*) to get the desired result.

---

Why the two bounds work? The first one is again a pointwise inequality:
$$
Z \cdot 1_{\{Z \le a\}} \le a. 
$$
The LHS is either 0 or when nonzero it is $\le a$. We then take the expectation of both sides which is valid since expectation is a "monotone" operator (i.e., preserves inequalities).

The second bound is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality which for random variables reads
$$
E|XY| \le \sqrt{E X^2} \sqrt{E Y^2}.
$$
Apply this with $X = Z$ and $Y = 1_{\{Z > a\}}$ and note that $E Y^2 = E Y = P(Z > a)$. The first equality is since $Y^2 = Y$ (why?) and the second equality is since the expectation of an indicator variable is the probability of the underlying event, basically by the definition of expectation.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Comment: You are welcome.